# Android translucent card/layout like timely app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cards

I'm trying to copy this layout out of the beautiful Android Timely app

[image]

Specifically, the translucent box that has all the alarm info inside it. Not sure if it's a layout with a slightly different fill color than the background with the alpha value set really high.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this:

Manifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:theme="@style/PopupTheme"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:name="your.package.Activity">
</activity>
```

Styles.xml

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Base.CompactMenu.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

Color.xml //You can play with the alpha value

```
<color name="transparent_black">#A0000000</color>
```

myLayout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/transparent_black">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/guardar"
                style="@style/boton_aceptar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/action_save"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the result: the white part it's gonna be the current screen in the phone.
[image: My transparent activity]

Comment: Benn, I'll try it tonight and see if it's what I'm looking for.